# To find no.of columns in a data set with correlation more than certain percentage in R

Tags: r

I am working on a data set with 48 variables and by seeing the correlation plot in R, most of the variables are highly correlated. I am trying to find the number of variables that are correlated > 70%

My data frame is called `diagnosed_data` and the code I use is:

```
cor_data <- cor(diagnosed_data) 
corrplot::corrplot(cor_data, method = "number", 
                   title = "correlation plot b/w the attributes")
```

From this plot I can figure out visually how many variables have high correlation, but I would like to find this using code instead.

How can I find those variables? Any help would me much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please produce the code that you tried along with a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: Hi @amrrs, below is the code i used to plot a correlation plot among all the variables                                                                                    cor_data <- cor(diagnosed_data)
corrplot::corrplot(cor_data,method = "number",title = "correlation plot b/w the attributes"),    I can plot a correlation plot with the correlation value showing in the graph form which i can figure out the attributes which have correlation >70%. but i would like to find the no.of variables with >70% correlation with the help of code. Hope it is clear. Thanks:)

Comment: Number of variables correlated with what? Correlation implies a comparison of two variables. Do you mean number of pairs of variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use the `mtcars` dataset, which has 10 variables (instead of your 48 variables).

There are `10(10-1)/2` unique correlation pairs. If you look at the correlation matrix, this corresponds to the elements above the diagonal. By checking whether the correlation is larger than 0.7 (or smaller than -0.7) for those upper-triangular elements, we can see how many unique pairs are heavily correlated:

```
cor_mat     <- cor(mtcars)
unique_cors <- cor_mat[upper.tri(cor_mat)]
sum(abs(unique_cors) > 0.7)
# [1] 19
```

And if you want to just get a `TRUE` or `FALSE` indication for every pair, you could use:

```
abs(cor_mat) > 0.7
       mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
mpg   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
cyl   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
disp  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
hp    TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
drat FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
wt    TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
qsec FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
vs   FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
am   FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
gear FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
carb FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you store results in a dataframe and analyse it further. Using the `mtcars` dataset as well.

```
library(dplyr)

t(combn(names(mtcars), 2)) %>%                          # get all pairwise combinations of variables
  data.frame(., stringsAsFactors = F) %>%               # save as dataframe
  rowwise() %>%                                         # for each row (pair)
  mutate(cor_value = cor(mtcars[X1], mtcars[X2])) %>%   # calculate correlation value
  ungroup()                                             # forget the grouping

# # A tibble: 55 x 3
#      X1    X2  cor_value
#   <chr> <chr>      <dbl>
# 1   mpg   cyl -0.8521620
# 2   mpg  disp -0.8475514
# 3   mpg    hp -0.7761684
# 4   mpg  drat  0.6811719
# 5   mpg    wt -0.8676594
# 6   mpg  qsec  0.4186840
# 7   mpg    vs  0.6640389
# 8   mpg    am  0.5998324
# 9   mpg  gear  0.4802848
# 10   mpg  carb -0.5509251
# # ... with 45 more rows
```

You can try different correlation thresholds, you can get all pairs of variables that are correlated above a specified threshold, you can get the variables that appear in most pairs, etc.

And a version without grouping, but by using a user specified vectorised function:

```
f_get_cor = function(x,y) { cor(mtcars[x], mtcars[y]) }
f_get_cor = Vectorize(f_get_cor)


t(combn(names(mtcars), 2)) %>%
  data.frame(., stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  mutate(cor_value = f_get_cor(X1, X2))
```